# Getting an infinite loop in pandas when creating a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to create a function that

- receives two separate CSV files,
- finds differences between them and
- create a third CSV file which is populated with the rows that fall into a certain category (if the value of CSV A in row #1 is present in any row in CSV B)

but this is creating me an infinite loop.

It *should* return about 20-25 rows but it's caught in a loop and creating over 200 million before VSCode gives up and shuts off

```
def valorPivoteo(ftth_osp, pivote, dataLoader):
    # for a, sig in array_sig.iterrows():
    #     for b, sig in array_osp.iterrows():
    fila = pd.DataFrame({"FTTH": [ftth_osp], "ID": pivote})
    dataLoader = pd.concat([dataLoader, fila])
    return dataLoader



## Main which calls the previous def
for i, sig in array_sig.iterrows():
    for j, osp in array_osp.iterrows():
        if(etc):
                etc

        elif(etc):
            etc

        else:
            buscarIDOSP = buscarID(valor_sig, array_osp)
            

            if(buscarIDOSP == False):
                x = valorReemplazo(ftth_osp, ftth_sig, valor_sig, valor_osp, dataLoader)
                dataLoader = pd.concat([dataLoader, x], ignore_index=True)
                break
            elif(buscarIDOSP == True):
                y = valorPivoteo(ftth_osp, pivote, dataLoader)
                dataLoader = pd.concat([dataLoader, y], ignore_index=True)
                pivote+=1
                break
```

Tried condensing the code so it's not so tiresome to read, tried creating an if so it breaks after certain value in i or j is achieved, or putting a break here and there, but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, in the def I shouldn't be doing a concat between dataLoader and fila. I should just create fila, add them the values and then return it. That just fixes it.

So in summary:

```
def valorPivoteo(ftth_osp, valor_osp, pivote, dataLoader):
    fila = pd.DataFrame({"FTTH": [ftth_osp], "ID": pivote})
    return fila
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!